# 3rd Party DLLs with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, emgucv

I would like to use a 3rd party wrapper dll in an asp.net core project. (Emgucv)
The Problem is: The .net Wrapper expects several DLLS in \x86 or \x64 folder in a traditional .net \bin directory.

I tried packing the two folders in a nugetpackage and adding that to my project, but that does not seem to help.

I have no clue how this could work out in asp.net core.... or if there even is a way?

Will it work to create an additional ("oldschool") net dll, handling my 3rd party stuff?

Comment: Please use the proper tags in future! When your quesiton is related to ASP.NET Core use "asp.net-core" tag ! NOT "asp.net" and "core", both are completely unrelated to your question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them

Comment: @Tseng when editing a question, please also edit out fluff that doesn't add to the question. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks, I was mainly fixing the tags of a few of dozen of completely mistagged questions (asp.net + core, rather than asp.net-core)